# Problems installing Dajaxice properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I have dajaxice installed on my python2.6 dist-packages folder, that seems to work alright with importing the stuff. But it throws all kinds of errors, since the django template tags are not being rendered.

> invalid property id [Break on this
>   error] {% for module in
>   dajaxice_js_functions %}\n

Makes sense, so I tried putting the js into HTML straight, which solves some of the problems of the templatetags, but gets messed up again, probably since its looking for dajaxice_core_loop.js

> invalid property id
>   [Break on this error] ,\n

I kept on uncommenting JS that throws me errors, but here i stripped it down to an extent that it is not working at all (duh). Because when I recreate the example with the button and hit the button i get:

> Dajaxice.MYAPP is undefined

of course, MYAPP is my specific application that holds the ajax.py

I guess I am doing it all wrong, but I can't really tell from the documentation what that might be specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that I shoulnd't have configured that Nginx serves my js statically, resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Quick note: on the Django development server I had to place the Dajaxice URL entry before the static media so it could parse the javascript correctly.